# How to validate if all elements in a vector equal to a scalar in R?

Tags: r, vector, conditional-statements

lets assume we have this vector:

```
v <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
```

Is there a function that validates if all elements in a vector are equal to a scallar?

In other words `v == 1` returns `TRUE` ?

Comment: must it be just `1` or a vector like `c(2,2,2,2,2)` also??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `min()` and `max()`:

```r
v <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
max(v) == 1 && min(v) == 1

[1] TRUE
```

The logic here is that if the smallest and largest values in the incoming vector are both 1, then *all* values must 1.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `all` ?

```
all(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1) == 1)
[1] TRUE

all(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2) == 1)
[1] FALSE
```